# How is the python assignment "mylist[:] = somelist" different from "mylist = somelist"

Tags: python, syntax, slice

I'm filtering the directory components using os.walk():

```
exclude_dirs = ['a', 'b']
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mytopdir):
  dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude_dirs]  # 1. Works
  dirs = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude_dirs]     # 2. Doesn't work
```

It seems like the second one is making a new local variable which hides the original dirs.  How is the first one doing things that it avoids this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dirs[:] = ...` modifies `dirs` *inplace*. 
`dirs = ...` [reassigns the variable](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) `dirs` to a new object. The directories visited by `os.walk` is affected only if the object that `dirs` originally refers to is *modified inplace*.

`dirs[:] = ...` is a form of [slice assignment](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

```
In [18]: dirs = range(10)

In [19]: dirs
Out[19]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [20]: id(dirs)
Out[20]: 158391724
```

This slice assignment replaces the values in `dirs[5:8]` with the characters in `'hello'`. Notice that the number of items in the slice (3) do not need to equal the number of items in the assignment (5).

```
In [21]: dirs[5:8] = 'hello'

In [22]: dirs
Out[22]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 8, 9]
```

The id does not change:

```
In [23]: id(dirs)
Out[23]: 158391724
```

When start and stop slice indices are omitted, the slice is taken to be the entire list:

```
In [24]: dirs[:] = 'cheese'

In [25]: dirs
Out[25]: ['c', 'h', 'e', 'e', 's', 'e']
```

Notice that again the `id` does not change. That's an indication that `dirs` points to the same object, and the modification was done inplace.

```
In [26]: id(dirs)
Out[26]: 158391724
```

In contrast, if you reassign `dirs` to some other value, then the `id` changes, because it is now pointing at a different object.

```
In [27]: dirs = 'spam'

In [28]: id(dirs)
Out[28]: 181415008
```